# AngularJS - Dynamic DOM manipulation without hardcoding dom id's in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I'm still getting started with angular, and it seems that the "Angular way of things" is to **separate the view from the controller**, and as such, my DOM manipulation in angular seems very clunky so far since I have to do a lot of manual dom element selecting. My app currently looks something like this;

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="appController as appCtrl">
    <div>
        <div id="element1"></div>
        <div id="element2"></div>
        <div id="element3"></div>
        <button ng-click="appCtrl.animateStuff()"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
app.controller('appController', ['animationFactory', 'domFactory', appControllerFunc]);
function appControllerFunc(animationFactory, domFactory) {
    This = this;
    This.animateStuff = function() {
        animationFactory.animate(domFactory.getNgElementById('element1'));
        animationFactory.animate(domFactory.getNgElementById('element2'));
        animationFactory.animate(domFactory.getNgElementById('element3'));
    }
}
```

**FACTORIES:**

```
app.factory('domFactory', [domFactoryFunc]);
function domFactoryFunc() {
    var domFactoryContainer = {
        getNgElementById: function(id) {
            return angular.element(document.getELementById(id));
        }
    }
    return domFactoryContainer;
}

app.factory('animationFactory');
function animationFactoryFunc() {
    var animationFactoryContainer = {
        animate: function(ngelement) {
            // animates ngelement
        }
    }
    return animationFactoryContainer;
}
```

Is there a way to somehow send DOM elements to the controller from the view's ng-click? Something like ngclick="ctrl.animateStuff([#element1],[#element2],[#element3])" so my controller just needs to get the parameters and manipulate them without even knowing anything about the DOM? Or can directives be used for this? if so, how?

Comment: You are right - "the "Angular way of things" is to separate the view from the controller" - so DON'T make any assumptions (such as element Ids) about the DOM in the controller. In other words, if you feel that you need to access the DOM from the controller, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Added more information to my question, sorry, it seems to have been cut off when I wrote it down and copied-pasted it from notepad

Comment: Read about how to do animation in Angular, with [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate). It uses the element, but it's not in the controller.

Comment: I'm using my own customized animation library using GSAP since I'm building a mobile first native-like application that uses hardware accelerated complex animations, so I need that library to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use Angular's ngAminate (which doesn't require DOM manipulation as it uses css), you can build a custom [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Directives are where DOM manipulation is allowed and you'd get the actual element passed into the directive, so there's no need for hard-coded ids.

But I recommend following @NewDev's suggestion.

This would be a possible stub for the directive:

```
module.directive('myAnimation', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      enabled: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      // watch on enabled and start animation when set to true
    }
  }
});
```

And your markup:

```
<div my-animation enabled='enabled'></div>
<div my-animation enabled='enabled'></div>
<div my-animation enabled='enabled'></div>
<button ng-click="enabled=true"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To unblock you right now, you could do

```
<div id="element1" ng-click="ctrl.animateStuff($event)"></div>
```

that would pass the event to your function and you could extract the DOM element from it.

I'm not familiar with GSAP, but you should be able to hook it into ngAnimate-way of doing things.

And, I would repeat myself - **DON'T access or make any assumption about the DOM in your controller** - you are breaking Angular's best practices and will often find yourself with problems and headaches.

Comment: If not in the controller, where am I supposed to manipulate the DOM? Also, I've used $event parameter before,the problem here is I don't need to get the calling element, I need multiple items next to it (which I know I could get by using closest() with the calling item but that still requires DOM id hard-coding)

Comment: Read about [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) - this is where animation related DOM manipulation is happening.